# What happens to an activity inicator view in a tableview cell when doing [tableView reloadData]

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview, reloaddata

I have a `UITableView` in my app that shows values fetched from a server. When the value is not ready, I show a `UIActivityIncicatorView` in my tableviewcell instead of the value.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    ...

    UIActivityIndicatorView *throbber = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    throbber.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
    cell.accessoryView = throbber;
    [throbber startAnimating];

    ...
}
```

What I'm curious about is, what happens to the animating `UIActivityIndicatorView` when I'm reloading the tableView? (Values can become ready and trigger a `[tableView reloadData]` at different times).

The `reloadData` call will call the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method and recreating the `UIActivityIndicatorView`.

It seems like sometimes, the animation is persisted across the `reloadData` call and sometimes the animation restarts and it looks like the app is hacking.

So does anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

1 You can create custom cell inheritув акщь UITableViewCell and create UIActivityIndicatorView in this cell, so when you will reuse your cell UIActivityIndicatorView will not be recreated. You will need call some custom method to start animation in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
[cell startActivitiIndicatorAnimation]
```

2 something like this

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *throbber = nil;
if ([cell.accessoryView isKindOfClass:[UIActivityIndicatorView class]])
{
    throbber = (UIActivityIndicatorView *)cell.accessoryView;
} else {
    throbber = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    throbber.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24);
    cell.accessoryView = throbber;
}

[throbber startAnimating];
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead, add that indicator to cell as subview, create variable to it and start/stop or show/hide when appropriate. This way indicator will be animating without recreating.